# Magento: Change the order of “Additional Information” attributes

Tags: magento-1.7

Is there a way to change the order of the attributes displayed on the Product View Page under the "Additional Information" section?

I find that every time I select an attribute to be displayed on the Product View Page, it gets added to the bottom of the list.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Ahh! Found it!

You can change the order of attributes by changing the order that they appear on your attribute set.

Easy!